# Laravel make a resource available to only guest users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my route:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');

});
```

I want the `restaurants.create` to be available for guest users.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the route outside of the `Route Group` like this:

```
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
```

Instead of this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
});
```

Then in your `RestaurantsController` controller add the `before` filter inside the `__construct` method like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); // If BaseController has a __construct method
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('create')));
}
```

So all the methods will have `auth` as the `before` filter but without the `create` method. If you need to add another `before` filter then you may add another one just after the first one like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct(); // If BaseController has a __construct method

    // Add auth as before filter for all methods but not for create
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array('create')));

    // Only for create method
    $this->beforeFilter('anotherFilter', array('only' => array('create')));
}
```

Comment: Hi, where have you been :) I will come back to this question tomorrow morning because it belongs to another project. Now I have this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518012/laravel-one-to-one-relationship I wanna kill myself to understand this `one-to-one` relationship. Could you help pleeeeeease?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the `guest` filter, which should be included by default.

So change the line from:

`Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {`

to:

`Route::group(array('before' => 'guest'), function() {`