# laravel one to one relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I have `xml_document` table with these columns:

```
id
general_information_id
```

I have `general_information` table with these columns:

```
id
domain
log_file
```

The relationship between them is one to one.

Have I build the relationship correctly? Or I need to add `xml_document_id` column to the `general_information` table.

Secondly:

I have added a row to the `xml_doucment` and now I want to add a row to the `general_information` and link this new row to the `xml_document`

I tried this:

```
 $xmlDocument = XmlDocument::find(Input::get(4));
            $generalInformation = new GeneralInformation($dataGeneralInformation);
            $generalInformation->xmlDocument()->associate($xmlDocument);
            //$xmlDocument->generalInformation()->attach($generalInformation);
            $generalInformation->save();
            $xmlDocument->save();
```

but I got error that `xml_document_id` column doesn't exist in the `general_information` table.

I tried to replace `associate` with `attach` but I got that `attach` is not an existed function.

please help me I am tried of this one to one relationship, I couldn't know what is the correct way to do id. I don't know where to add columns in the database and what to do in the models. I have tried a lot of things but still so confused.

#### Update 1

```
class GeneralInformation extends  Eloquent{
.....   
public function xmlDocument(){
        return $this->belongsTo('XmlDocument');
    }
}


class XmlDocument extends Eloquent {
....
 public  function  generalInformation(){
        return $this->hasOne('GeneralInformation','general_information_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly why would anyone downvote a question like this? at least leave a note. I have been trying to understand this issue for 4 days. And I showed you a good efforts.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted, but it was probably because of the poor formatting and the lack the most important part of the code, your Models'.

Comment: You should provide more information, how both tables are related, which one is the `foreign key` in child table and who is the child here?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha it is a one to one relationship so a part of the question is to tell me please if I should make a foreign key in the `general_information` table or not. and should I put two foreign keys? one in each table? that is not possible, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a `one-to-one` relationship, you need to store the `primary key` of parent table in the child table as a `foreign key`. So if `xml_document` is parent and if it contains many `general_information` then the `id` field of the `xml_document` should be present in in the `general_information` table as `xml_document_id`.

So, you may build the `one-to-one` relation like this:

```
// xml_document model
public function generalInfo()
{
    return $this->hasOne('GeneralInformation');
}
```

Then the declare the `GeneralInformation` model.

Comment: so you are saying that I need to remove the `general_information_id` from the `xml_document` table and add a `xml_document_id` into the `general_information` table? right?

Comment: I didn't understand your point by `parent`, but if in a relationship like a `person` to `pictures`,(one to many) the parent is the `person`, so here the parent is the `xmldocument`. each xml document has a `general_information` (one table) and a `details_information` (another table) and a `master_information` (another table). got me my friend?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the same exact code will be for one to one and one to many except the hasOne to hasMany. right? exact code in database and in laravel model

Comment: Then your `general_information` table should contain `xml_document_id` and `xml_document.id` should be `primary key` in `xml_document` table and `xml_document_id` should be `foreign key` in `general_information` table.

Comment: Yes, `one-to-one` should be same using `hasOne`.

Comment: I am really sorry for keep asking but just last thing, If I want to know if an xmldocument model has a generalinformation model or not. can I say this `$xmldocument->generalInformation()==null` ?

Comment: `generalInformation()` should be `generalInformation` but you may query like `$xmldocument->has('generalInformation')->get()` so only those `xmldocument` will be loaded who has a related `generalInformation` model.

Comment: I did this `$xmldocument= XmlDocument::find(4);
        if(isset($xmldocument->generalInformation))
            echo "set";
        else
        echo "not set";exit;` but I got `not set` though I have a row in my `general_information` table witch its `xml_document_id` is `4` and when I click on that column in my mysql database, the xmldocuent with id = `4` opens

Comment: use `XmlDocument::with('generalInformation')->find(4)`. here `generalInformation` should be the relation method.

Comment: you mean to use it like this `if(isset(XmlDocument::with('generalInformation')->find(4)))` ?

Comment: `$xmldocument= XmlDocument::with('...')->find(4);`

Comment: I created a new account because I couldn't ask more than 50 questions in 30 days. please check my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556875/php-change-php-array-to-xml-format

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
class GeneralInformation extends  Eloquent
{
  public function xmlDocument()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('XmlDocument');
  }
}


class XmlDocument extends Eloquent
{

  public function generalInformation()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('GeneralInformation','general_information_id');
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks but I already got an answer. Plus, the code your provided is exactly the code I showed in the question.

Comment: Actually it's not. `hasOne` and `belongsTo` are switched, as you had them backwards in your question. That was the key. The parent table (the table w/ the foreign key) always `hasOne` of the child table (the table w/o the foreign key). And the child always `belongsTo`  the parent.